# how to make a trigger for another table mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have 2 tables

tbl 1

```
id  product_id  quantity    status
```

tbl 2

```
id  product_id  status
```

with tbl1.product_id = tbl2.product_id, i want to make a trigger, so if i update  tbl1.status in tbl1.product_id, then it will become automatically update status for tbl2.product_id with the same value of the status

so if let's say the table was like this

```
tbl1

    +----+------------+----------+--------+
    | id | product_id | quantity | status |
    +----+------------+----------+--------+
    |  1 |         15 |        2 |      1 |
    |  2 |         16 |        4 |      1 |
    +----+------------+----------+--------+

tbl2

    +----+------------+--------+
    | id | product_id | status |
    +----+------------+--------+
    |  1 |         15 |      1 |
    |  2 |         16 |      1 |
    +----+------------+--------+
```

If i want to update tbl1.product_id = 15 into status = 0, then tbl2.product_id = 15 will become status = 0 too like this

```
tbl1
    
        +----+------------+----------+--------+
        | id | product_id | quantity | status |
        +----+------------+----------+--------+
        |  1 |         15 |        2 |      0 |
        |  2 |         16 |        4 |      1 |
        +----+------------+----------+--------+

    tbl2
    
        +----+------------+--------+
        | id | product_id | status |
        +----+------------+--------+
        |  1 |         15 |      0 |
        |  2 |         16 |      1 |
        +----+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Does different `status` value in linked rows makes sense? if not then simply remove this column from dependent table. *i have 2 tables* Show them as complete CREATE TABLE scripts.

Comment: that's a long story, but ```tbl1``` has been made before ```tbl2```, ```tbl2``` basically just contains some ```product_id``` in ```tbl1``` that has ```status``` = 1. long story short, there's condition that ```status``` in ```tbl1``` will be updated, so i need the trigger, when i update the status in ```tbl1``` then it will automatically update too in ```tbl2``` for same ```product_id```

Comment: Oh yes, i forgot, ```tbl2``` has contained ```product_id``` on all of the tables, including ```tbl1``` so it should be another column in ```tbl2``` to give the information where the ```product_id``` coming from, but i think it's not relate with this case, so I remove it for the cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_table2
AFTER UPDATE
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE table2
    SET status = NEW.status
    WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i want to know, can i put code after ```ON table1``` with condition related to ```table1``` ? so lets say i want to put ```AFTER UPDATE ON table1 WHERE table1.another_column = 'yes'```

Comment: so when the edit has be done in ```table1.another_column = no```, then the trigger will not be done

Comment: @18818181881 Add according check into WHERE clause of the UPDATE query. `... AND NEW.another_column = 'no'`.

Comment: so the format that i mentioned before it's right? ```AFTER UPDATE ON table1 WHERE table1.another_column = 'yes'```

Comment: but that ```another_column``` its just only in ```table1``` not in ```table2```

Comment: @18818181881 No. `WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id AND NEW.another_column = 'no'`

Comment: i see, let me try it